# How to compress long JSON from node and use that in client side (browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, encoding, compression

I'm sending some initial `json` data from next.js server component to client component.
The issue is that payload is large, Actual data (with escape slash) is around 13kb.
Want to compress it as much as possible & decompress in the client component to avoid that huge payload on each page (as I'm doing it in layout).

*I've done some test with deflate (using node zlib / deflate) & seen that can reduce data size to 1/3.

For clarity following is the scenario:

```js
// layout.ts
// want to compress "hugeData" to save initial payload size of pages
<AclientComponent jsonData={hugeData} />
```

```js
// AclientComponent.ts
const AclientComponent = ({jsonData}: {JSONData}) => {
   // decode "jsonData" & may be set it to zustand or something like this.
}
export default AclientComponent;
```